# c# how to extract files paths with a certain extension and retrieve its parent folder name

Tags: c#

I have a folder structure as follows, The top two folder structure is predictable such DrawingFiles and project name which will be any random number. I am trying to extract files with an extension of ".dwg" from a project folder.

The complexity is that within the project folder, there could be any number of random number of folder and the ".dwg" file(s) could be in any folder or multiple folders. My goal is to extract all file paths of ".dwg" file from each project folder and the folder that any given dwg file is found, that folder becomes the discipline folder. I want to extract project name, discipline name and list of dwg files within.

```
DrawingFiles
          >12345
            >xyz12
               >Engr
                 a.dwg
                 b.dwg
               >Elec
                 c.dwg
                 f.dwg
          >45678
            >xyz12
                 at.dwg
                 bt.dwg
             >Elec
                 b.dwg
                 l.dwg
             >spec1
                 >Struct
                   123.dwg
```

Comment: _Directory.GetFiles_ should be enough. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this method by passing the known folder path:

```
private List<String> DirSearch(string rootDir)
{
    List<String> files = new List<String>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootDir))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f);
            if(fi.Extension==".dwg"){
                string parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(rootDir).FullName;
                files.Add(parent);

            }
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(rootDir))
        {
            files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: Directory.GetFiles does all this by itself. There is an overload that takes a file pattern and an option to execute a recursive search in the subfolders. This code is not needed. _Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, "*.dwg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);_

Comment: I am trying to retrieve a list which contains discipline name and file path(s) within

Comment: Just in case if some files are present in some directory without extension and also as this is a recursion, problem with one file should not stop the entire processing.

Answer (score 2):

```
var directories = Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, "*.dwg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                           .Select(Path.GetDirectoryName)
                           .ToHashSet();
```

`directories` will contain the unique directories paths (each folder will be repeated only once).